# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^3}{ \sqrt {1-r^2}}dr$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

Evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^3}{ \sqrt {1-r^2}}dr$$

My attempt : I put  $t= \sqrt{1-r^2}$ now  $dt/dr= \frac{-r}{2\sqrt {1-r^2}}$ $$\implies dr=\frac{2\sqrt {1-r^2}}{r}dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^3}{ \sqrt {1-r^2}}\frac{2\sqrt {1-r^2}}{r}dt$$

$$= 2\int_{0}^{1} r^2 dt$$

$t= \sqrt{1-r^2}\implies r^2= t^2-1$

$$2\int_{0}^{1} t^2-1 dt= 2[\frac{t^3}{3} -t]_{0}^{1}==-4/3$$

Comment: Quick check: the result should be a positive number. Please check: $r^2=1-t^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just integration by parts:

\begin{eqnarray*}\int_0^1 r^2 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr
& = & \left.-\sqrt{1-r^2}\cdot r^2\right|_0^1 + \int_0^1 (2r)\sqrt{1-r^2}\;dr \\
& = & \left.-\frac 23\left(1-r^2\right)^{\frac 32}\right|_0^1 \\
& = & \frac 23
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: creative answer !!

Comment: @jasmine Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since $t= \sqrt{1-r^2}$, we should have $dt/dr = \frac {-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ and $t^2 + r^2 = 1$.

Now

$$\int_0^1 \frac {r^3}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr = \int_{\color{red}1}^{\color{red}0} \frac {r^3}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\frac {\sqrt{1-r^2}}{-r}dt = \int_0^1r^2dt = \int_0^1(\color{red}{1-t^2})dt = [t-\frac{t^3}3]_0^1 = \frac23$$

Answer (score 1):

With $r=\sin t$ it's$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3tdt=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin t-\sin t\cos^2t)dt=[\tfrac13\cos^3t-\cos t]_0^{\pi/2}=\tfrac23.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r^3 dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$
Let $r=\sin t \implies dr= \cos t dt$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^3 t dt=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin t(1-\cos^2 t) dt$$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\sin t -\cos^2 t \sin t) dt$$
$$ I=-\cos t+\frac{\cos^3 t}{3}|_{0}^{\pi/2}=-(-1+1/3)=2/3.$$